# Large jpeg using more memory than smaller jpeg when loaded in a UIImageView. Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory, uiimageview, jpeg

The login view in our app uses large background images. To try and save on memory/app size I resized and compressed these images, which reduced their filesize significantly (less than 1mb, down from several mb).

When monitoring my apps memory usage (XCode debugger) there is a clear spike when a modified image is displayed (around 30-40mb). I'd accepted this as normal and simply made sure to release the image asap to limit memory usage.

I've recently started replacing a couple of the images and wanted to preview the new ones before resizing/compressing them. I noticed that these images (one of which is 11mb on disk and 4640x3472 pixels) has no visible effect on app memory usage whatsoever, increasing 'Other Processes' instead (by around 20-30mb).

Can anyone explain what's happening here? I want to confirm it is advisable to continue resizing/compressing the images.

Note that I'm loading the images using `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` and I resized/compressed the images using GIMP. The new images have been taken straight from Flickr and unmodified.

Cheers.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the images? You give the dimensions for the large file but not the small one.

Comment: @user3344003 sorry for the delay responding. The smaller file has dimensions of 3788x2532. 

The device I'm working on is an iPad Mini 4th Gen.

Answer (score 1):

The in-memory size of the image (as a `UIImage`) is different to the compressed on-disk size (your JPEG)

The `UIImage` takes 4 bytes (RGBA) per pixel x height x with - so for a 4640 x 3472 image, you're looking at 64,440,320 bytes - quite different to the 11MB on disk

Comment: I understand that the file on disk is not equal to the actual memory required to render it in the app. I'm confused by the difference in memory behaviour between a small (500kb) jpeg and the large (11mb) one you mention. 

Specifically, the smaller file appears to use more app memory than the large file, which on the face of it seems odd. The smaller files also seem to directly contribute to the apps memory footprint, whereas the larger files look to be handled elsewhere by the OS.